# Wrapping around lists with complex functions, iteration on numbered variables

Tags: python, list, python-2.x

I am not a programmer, and as such, I am learning on the fly by searching on forums like this. 
Bear with me, as I am not even conding on native Python, but inside an application that have a Python interpreter to allow to code specific processing

I have seen examples of what I am about to ask, but they dont quite resemble what I need, so I need to ask more specifically

Q1: I have a dataset with waveforms (list arrays) over time. The naming convention is for example `WF001`, `WF002`, ..., `WF009`. I found in this forum how to iterate over the variables with the `global()` function. Example below using just the first item on the list `(1,1)`

```
g=globals()
import ViewerStat as stat #this is a library from the application

print g["WF00"+str(1)].value(1,1) #this command works fine.
```

but

```
for i in range(1,9):
       print g["WF00"+str(i)].value(1,1) # this do not work
```

and I want to eventually assign values to a composed waveform
the below code do not work at all

```
for i in range (1,9)
      g["NEW_WF00"+str(i)].value(1,1)=stat.median([g["WF00"+str(i)].value(1,1),g["WF00"+str(i+1)].value(1,1),g["WF00"+str(1+2)].value(1,1)])
```

Note: the `stat.median()` function does work when printed and not iterated

```
print stat.median([g["WF00"+str(1)].value(1,1),g["WF00"+str(2)].value(1,1),g["WF00"+str(3)].value(1,1)])
```

So I have the problem of iterating over this variable, and then to assign using `globals()` after making a mathematical functions

Q2: the length of the list is around 300 elements. I will calculate the median with the adjacent waveforms, and I need to wrap around the lists, for example, the median of the element 300 will be computed with elements 199, 200 and 1. With the naming complications listed above, how can I wrap around without doing a separate loop for the boundaries of the list? This might be a small thing, but my dataset is very large and I am doing a lot of computations. Remember the example above are a single time index, but I have over 150000 time indexes and about 150 waveforms

Comment: "I found in this forum how to iterate over the variables with the global() function." Where? Because I *really* what to go there and downvote whoever suggested this. Do *not* use `globals()`. Put the `WF` variables into a list and iterate over the list. Besides "does not work" does *not* mean *anything*! If it raises an exception post the *full* traceback, if it gives a result that you do not expect post the actual result *and* what you expected!

Comment: @Bakuriu: I'm 200% with you in spirit, but it's at least possible that the environment that the OP is in injects its data structures into the embedded Python globals().  If `g["WF00"+str(1)]` works, then this might be what's going on, although the OP's update seems to rule this out.  The first move would still probably be to extract them from `globals()` and put them into a list or a more useful dictionary, though.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any error output about why this line

```
print g["WF00"+str(i)].value(1,1) # this do not work
```

doesn't work?

Perhaps something about an invalid key? It looks like "g" is a dictionary so moving forward making this assumption I would try printing out g.keys() to see what keys are available. Generally when looping over a dictionary I do:

```
for key in g.keys():
  g[key].value(1,1)
```

this will ensure that you only access keys that are actually there, where as what you had

```
for i in range(1,9):
       print g["WF00"+str(i)].value(1,1) # this do not work
```

could potentially access elements that aren't set.

The line above I gave

```
g[key].value(1,1)
```

also makes the assumption, based on your code, that the dictionary has objects that have a `value()` function, which may or may not be true. Anyhow.. these are mostly guess at your problem, some error output would make this answer much more focused.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the error I get in the line

```
print g["WF00"+str(i)].value(1,1)
```

is

```
KeyError: 'WF001'
```

when performing print g.keys() I get this list. As I mention I am not a programmer, and these jeys mean not much to me.

```
['gt', 'help', 'SQRT2', 'random', 'imul', 'ge', 'TechlogMath', 'sqrt', 'acosh', '__package__', 'getDatasetZoneIndiceTop', 'ParameterProxy', 'LOG2E', 'le', 'getitem', 'Histogram', 'frexp', 'platform', 'add', 'delslice', 'degrees', 'outputTL', 'division', 'rshift', 'factorial', '__file__', 'findNearestIndexBefore', 'ceil', 'unitValueListConvert', 'iconcat', 'isCallable', 'mod', 'isub', '__group__', 'd', 'printError', 'radians', 'sin', 'setitem', 'SQRTH', 'fmod', 'output', 'div', 'LOOP', 'findNearestIndexUnsortedUncleanData', 'findNearestIndex', 'boxCox', 'not_', 'cosh', 'hypot', 'UF001', 'parameterDict', 'E', 'isMappingType', 'eq', 'asin', 'isnan', 'xor', 'sub', 'HistoryItem', 'MissingValue', 'sequenceIncludes', 'getslice', 'truth', 'LogView', 'indexOf', 'abs', 'exit', 'idiv', 'mul', 'PI', 'UN001', 'irepeat', 'is_', 'modf', '__builtins__', 'copysign', 'ws', 'sinh', 'ipow', 'LOOP_INV', 'trunc', 'or_', 'cos', 'CrossPlot', 'g', 'outputSHerr', 'CacheVarData', 'itruediv', 'ProgressBar', 'erfc', 'w', 'pow10', 'acos', 'LOOP_ARRAY_MVTEST', 'os', 'gamma', 'delitem', 'iand', 'countOf', 'pythonEditor', 'pow', 'fsum', 'pos', 'TechlogRealTime', 'ldexp', '__suffix__', 'and_', 'lshift', '__name__', 'ixor', '__prefix__', 'TechlogPlot', 'plot', 'LOOP_ARRAY', 'winId', 'log', 'invert', 'contains', 'lt', 'isSequenceType', 'irshift', 'Variable', 'PrintErrorLimit', 'limitValue', 'pi', 'log10', 'outputSH', 'exp10', 'asinh', 'expm1', 'LN2', 'iif', 'PIO2', 'LOOP_MVTEST', 'PIO4', 'TechlogStat', 'tanh', 'TechlogDatabase', '__doc__', 'lgamma', 'erf', 'getDatasetZoneIndiceBottom', 'isNumberType', 'ilshift', 'log1p', 'ifloordiv', 'almostEqual', 'outputLogger', 'inv', 'printErrorCount', 'LN10', 'tan', 'TechlogPlatform', 'iadd', 'LOOP_INV_ARRAY', 'fabs', 'floor', 'Parameter', 'atanh', 'ne', 'setslice', 'outputTLerr', 'attrgetter', 'ExitExpectedException', 'methodcaller', 'truediv', 'applyMode', '__techlog_database', 'LOOP_INV_MVTEST', 'boxCoxInv', 'unitValueConvert', 'stat', 'repeat', 'Serr', 'atan', 'index', 'LOG10E', 'db', 'ior', 'sys', 'printTest', 'isinf', 'Sout', 'is_not', 'concat', 'LOOP_INV_ARRAY_MVTEST', 'e', 'i', 'imod', 'atan2', 'floordiv', 'exp', 'neg', 'Array', 'itemgetter']
```

How exactly should I implement your example: ?

```
for key in g.keys():
  g[key].value(1,1)
```